# Add textblock to bottom of listview

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I need to put a textblock containing result count information at the bottom of a databound listview. It needs to be within the listview's scrollbars but not be affected by the scrollbars (it must always sit at the bottom of the listview).

Because a listview cannot contain a textblock directly I am achieving this by adding some padding at the bottom of the listview and using a negative margin to make a separate textblock appear as though it is part of the listview. The issue with this is that when the listview's horizontal scrollbar is displayed it covers the textblock. I could add code to figure out if the scrollviewer is displayed and then adjust the margins/paddings accordingly BUT at this stage it sounds like a hacky solution.

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of what you are trying to achieve please?

Comment: Within the scrollbars but not effect by scrollbars is not a logical UI in my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a ListView.. you can do something like this:

```
 <ScrollViewer>
    <StackPanel>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}" />
        <TextBlock />
    </StackPanel>
 </ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: This seems like the best solution. There is no reason to have something in the scrollbars but not affected by them. You can still have bindings such that the text block updates. I would suggest binding it to a converter that binds to the same source collection and returns the info like count and whatever else you want to display.